# is there any way to extract place details in google maps API?

Tags: python, api, data-extraction, serpapi

Currently I am using Serp Api to extract places, but there is some information left. Like Question and Answers, At this place.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/giaUG.png)

I have tried this code

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "device": "desktop",
  "engine": "google_maps",
  "q": "ENOC | 1086 | Opp Emirates Int School",
  "google_domain": "google.com",
  "ll": "@40.7455096,-74.0083012,14z",
  "data": "!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5f6cbec8c4424d:0x951dd76fff166da1!8m2!3d25.06475!4d55.1546667",
  "type": "place",
  "hl": "en",
  "api_key": "secret_api_key"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()
```

Comment: i have shared image above which is showing 'question and answers', 'At this place' which i want to extract but couldn't getting with this code.

Comment: Hey, @chintanbhimani. I'm a devrel at SerpApi. Currently, we don't extract Q&A data from the Google Maps Place result. [I've opened a corresponding issue on our public roadmap](https://github.com/serpapi/public-roadmap/issues/520). Feel free to add additional details if needed. Thank you for letting us know about this 

Comment: @DmitriyZub and what about 'At this Place' ? like in image jailbird - meadows

Comment: @chintanbhimani currently we don't extract data from this section also. [I've created a separate feature request on our public-roadmap](https://github.com/serpapi/public-roadmap/issues/522).

Comment: @chintanbhimani ["at the place" results in supported now](https://github.com/serpapi/public-roadmap/issues/522). We've pushed this feature 2 days ago. Could you try this on your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["At this place" section has been recently added](https://github.com/serpapi/public-roadmap/issues/522), as well as ["Questions and Answers"](https://github.com/serpapi/public-roadmap/issues/520). Here's how you can access it:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import json

params = {
  "api_key": "your serpapi key",
  "device": "desktop",
  "engine": "google_maps",
  "type": "place",
  "hl": "en",
  "data": "!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e5f6cbec8c4424d:0x951dd76fff166da1!8m2!3d25.06475!4d55.1546667"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(results['place_results']['at_this_place']['type'])

print(json.dumps(results['place_results']['at_this_place']['places'], indent=2))

print(json.dumps(results['place_results']['questions_and_answers'], indent=2))
```

Outputs:

```json
[{'title': 'Food & Drink', 'places': 1}]
[
  {
    "position": 1,
    "title": "Jailbird - Meadows",
    "data_id": "0x3e5f6dc2b7d6a72b:0x99c79a98d0fa228c",
    "data_cid": "11080995389300155020",
    "reviews_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data_id=0x3e5f6dc2b7d6a72b%3A0x99c79a98d0fa228c&engine=google_maps_reviews&hl=en",
    "photos_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data_id=0x3e5f6dc2b7d6a72b%3A0x99c79a98d0fa228c&engine=google_maps_photos&hl=en",
    "gps_coordinates": {
      "latitude": 25.0651768,
      "longitude": 55.154764
    },
    "place_id_search": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?data=%214m5%213m4%211s0x3e5f6dc2b7d6a72b%3A0x99c79a98d0fa228c%218m2%213d25.0651768%214d55.154764&engine=google_maps&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&type=place",
    "rating": 188.0,
    "reviews": 4,
    "type": "Restaurant",
    "address": "Meadows Enoc station 1 Rd Meadows - opp. Emirates Int School - Dubai - United Arab Emirates",
    "open_state": "Open \u22c5 Closes 1AM",
    "hours": [
      {
        "wednesday": "11AM\u20131AM"
      },
      {
        "thursday": "11AM\u20131AM"
      },
      {
        "friday": "11AM\u20133AM"
      },
      {
        "saturday": "11AM\u20133AM"
      },
      {
        "sunday": "11AM\u20131AM"
      },
      {
        "monday": "11AM\u20131AM"
      },
      {
        "tuesday": "11AM\u20131AM"
      }
    ],
    "thumbanil": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipME1-tektJ33lViD4v1-w4exH0ced2wyoYTk9Zq=w86-h86-n-k-no"
  }
]

[
  {
    "question": {
      "user": {
        "name": "Selim Soliman",
        "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/114510311589225536034",
        "thumbnail": "https://lh4.ggpht.com/-Wq-1BTbSFgs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/Nb2aqnfEOzI/c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg"
      },
      "text": "When do you open",
      "date": "a month ago",
      "language": "en"
    },
    "answer": {
      "user": {
        "name": "Momen Abdalaziz",
        "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/114406017345938938689",
        "local_guide_level": 6,
        "thumbnail": "https://lh3.ggpht.com/-I_1mrBnJ0EY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/fKw4c8rVE2U/c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4/photo.jpg"
      },
      "text": "It is open 24 hours already",
      "date": "a month ago",
      "language": "en"
    },
    "total_answers": 1
  }
]
```

As a side note, you don't need to use `ll` when `data` parameter is used (place results).

This is because [`data` parameter](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-api#api-parameters-advanced-google-maps-parameters-data) holds the same information also, i.e latitude, and longitude except for zoom as in the [`ll` parameter](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-api#api-parameters-geographic-location-ll). In the case of place results, zoom is not needed :-)

Hope it makes sense.